# Bootstrap modal inside iframe remove content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have a 'big' problem with iframe. I had to make an iframe inside a container `div` witch has a Bootstrap modal inside. everything is working fine on desktop (Chrome, firefox, safari etc.)but on tablets, when i call the open function for the modal, it is remove every other content except the iframe.
here is the html code:

```
<div class="content">

        <div class="container-fluid header">
             <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">

                                <!-- SOME HTML CODE HERE-->
                   </div>
              </div>
        </div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <iframe src="/game/" width="100%" height="786" style="border: none" id="table-1"></iframe>
</div>
```

The iframe is an html document too, and i know that i souldn't had to use it for this, but thats what they want me to do.